# Create multiple tokens for a unique property

Tags: blockchain, tokens, erc-20, ethereum-wallet-dapp, erc-721

here is the idea:

we assign a set of unique tokens to a company and then we allow people to buy some tokens and  get partial ownership of that company. How can I achieve this? I was thinking of using ERC721 to create a non-fungible token for the company but I want a set of tokens not just one token.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You want partial ownership, so start with ERC20 tokens where total supply == 100% ownership. Other properties are materially different, therefore need a different token contract. Consider a contract factory to issue fractional ownership tokens for properties as they come online.

This project raises challenging concerns, so the foregoing is not presented as a complete solution; just a response to the question posed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. What do you mean by "Other properties are materially different"

Comment: I think perhaps I read more into the question than seems to be there on second read. I meant to say shares in company A are materially equal (fungible), but if there are other companies, shares in company B are materially different from shares in company A. In such a case, you would use different ERC20 contracts for each company.

Comment: Oh i see. That's really good point. I didn't think about that before.